# CSS not changing the form input box

Tags: html, css, forms

I have the following HTML code:

```css
.search{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
#searchForm{
  grid-template-columns: span 2; 
}
#labelFilter{
  grid-template-columns: 1/2;
}
#inputBox{
  grid-template-columns: 2/-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
    <form id="searchForm">
        <label id="labelFilter"> Filter shown with: </label>
        <input id="inputBox" value="">
    </form>
</div>
```

I want the final thing to look like this: (The lines are grid lines are shown for the purpose of demonstration):
[image]

**The search bar is not moving to the next half of the screen. How can I fix it?**

**Also, Chrome displays the `grid-template-column` property of the form , label and input as invalid property value. why?**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to make it this way.

**Snippet:**

```css
#searchForm {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
#labelFilter{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <form id="searchForm">
    <label id="labelFilter"> Filter shown with: </label>
    <input id="inputBox" value="">
  </form>
</div>
```

I hope this will works for you.

Thank you...

Comment: Why doesn't it work if I make the main div as grid but works if I make the form as grid?

Comment: you have to apply display: grid to the parent div or class. but you apply it to the grand parent. so it create a grid for you but #searchForm is the first grid content and second grid is empty.